# jfreechart - should adding a point to a dataset be on GUI thread?

Tags: jfreechart

When I incoke addition of a data point to a dataset, which is an underlying data set for some chart, by using the code:

```
 timeSeriesCollection.add(time, number);
```

does this have to be on the GUI thread, or would the updates to the chart, later up the listener chain, convert their updates to be on the GUI thread?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). This includes both view and model: `ChartPanel` (the view) renders your chart in response to events generated by updating your `TimeSeriesCollection` (the model).